# How do I find the size of a hex string in bytes using Python3 (with regex)

Tags: python, regex, hex, byte, python-3.7

I am tasked with writing a program using Python 3. I am new to Python.

I need to grab Hex data from a .bin file, and then partition the data every time I see the occurrence of a specific hex pattern (eg: each chunk starts with 01 03). Finally, I need to output the number of partitions and the size (in Bytes) of each chunk.

So far, I have read the data from the .bin file and used re.findall to partition each chunk of data. My regex statement looks something like this :

b"\x01\x03(?(?!\x01\x03).)*"

re.findall works well, but I now have a list of around 300 hex chunks (since i used re.findall), and I now don't know how to check the size in bytes for each chunk. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
regex = b'\x01\x03(?(?!\x01\x03).)*'

chunk_lengths = {index: len(chunk) for index, chunk in enumerate(re.findall(regex, data))}
```

You originally used `re.findall` to get every chunk in the source data which follows your given regex. These are `bytes` objects, which have a well-defined length (the number of bytes in them).

With the `len` operator, we can find the length of each chunk, and those will form the values of our dictionary. If we did `[len(chunk) for chunk in re.findall(regex, data))]`, that would give us a list of the lengths of all chunks found, *in the order they were found* (this will be important later).

`enumerate` is a built-in function that allows "tagging on" an index (starting from 0, by default) to some iterable object. So, say you have a `list` `[5, 3, 4]`, representing chunk lengths. If you apply `enumerate` to it, you'll get `tuple`s `(0, 5)` (index 0, length 5), `(1, 3)` (index 1, length 3) and `(2, 4)` (index 2, length 4).

Now, by putting everything together in a `dict` comprehension, we become more able to access the lengths of chunks by an index created by `enumerate`. Since, as noted above, `findall` returns a list of results in order, and enumerate also operates in order, the index created by `enumerate` is also the chunk's relative position in the original data.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain what this line does? Also, I can visually count the size of each frame, since each hex digit is half a byte. Is this actually counting the size of the chunk in bytes (for every chunk), or just finding the number of hexadecimal values in the chunk?

Comment: FYI, this code worked perfectly for me. I saw that chunk_lengths is now a dictionary, and I was able to continue solving the other problems after that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
l = re.compile("\x01\x03(?(?!\x01\x03).)*").split(s)
len(l) - 1
```

Test Result:

```
>>> re.compile(r"\x01\x03").split(b"\x01\x03\0x4\0x5\x01\x03\0x6\0x7")
['', '\x00x4\x00x5', '\x00x6\x00x7']
```

of course you should make sure that the regex is right.

Comment: Thanks! The regex seems to be correct. I tested it using regex101, and it splits the chunks accordingly. I will give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: Question: Does the s in 'split(s)' just represent the string that is being tested?

Comment: Test Results: 
``` 
>>> re.compile(r"\x01\x03").split(b"\x01\x03\0x4\0x5\x01\x03\0x6\0x7")
['', '\x00x4\x00x5', '\x00x6\x00x7']
```